# Execution times in C++ don't add up

Tags: c++, execution-time

I have been trying to improve the execution time of my program. The function below is a method of Class KAT, which also has references, samples and pointerMatrix as variables. There are 3 references and 3 samples. I started using smart pointers because the results from refAligner.align(sample) are large.

When I measure the execution time of each part individually, the total is somewhere between 400-500 seconds. However, the execution time of the entire function is twice that. I noticed that there's quite a wait between the last std::cout of "Add to matrix: " and the std::cout of "Entire alignment: ", so something is probably going on during that time but I don't know what. What is happening during this extra execution time? I'm happy to provide more code/info! Thanks!

```cpp
class KAT {

    private:
        std::string REFERENCES_FOLDER = "/References";
        std::string SAMPLES_FOLDER = "/Samples";
        Input input;
        References references;
        Filenames referenceFilenames;
        Samples samples;
        Filenames sampleFilenames;
        std::vector<std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Alignment>>> pointerMatrix;
        Results result;

        void readReferences();
        void calculateReferencesTextIndex();
        void readSamples();
        void createKmers();
        void alignAllSamplesToAllReferences();
        Results createResult();
        void copyAlignmentsToResult();


    public:
        KAT(Input input_): input(input_) { }
        
        Results align();

};
```

This is the problematic method.

```cpp
void KAT::alignAllSamplesToAllReferences() {

    auto start1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    
    for (Reference reference : references) {

        auto start2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        
        ReferenceAligner refAligner(reference);
        std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Alignment>> alignPointers;
        
        auto stop2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        auto duration2 = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(stop2 - start2);
        std::cout << "RefAligner Class: " << duration2.count() << std::endl;

        for (Sample sample: samples) {

            auto start3 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

            std::unique_ptr<Alignment> aligmentPointer = refAligner.align(sample);
            alignPointers.push_back(std::move(aligmentPointer));
            
            auto stop3 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
            auto duration3 = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(stop3 - start3);
            std::cout << "Align and pushback: " << duration3.count() << std::endl;
        }

        auto start4 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

        pointerMatrix.push_back(std::move(alignPointers));

        auto stop4 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        auto duration4 = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(stop4 - start4);
        std::cout << "Add to matrix: " << duration4.count() << std::endl;
    }

    auto stop1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration1 = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(stop1 - start1);
    std::cout << "Entire alignment: " << duration1.count() << std::endl;
}
```

These are the execution times I'm getting, they have been pretty consistent. If I add up the individual times I get 414 sec.

```
Aligning...
RefAligner Class: 0
Align and pushback: 12
Align and pushback: 44
Align and pushback: 21
Add to matrix: 0
RefAligner Class: 0
Align and pushback: 18
Align and pushback: 70
Align and pushback: 35
Add to matrix: 0
RefAligner Class: 0
Align and pushback: 46
Align and pushback: 115
Align and pushback: 53
Add to matrix: 0
Entire alignment: 999
Align all samples: 999
Create Results: 0
Writing results...
Main: 1171
```

Comment: `for (Reference reference : references)` -- can you describe what this mysterious `Reference` class is all about, and how much work would be involved in making a duplicate copy of each object in the equally mysterious `references` container, for this range iteration, and is that really needed? `for (Sample sample: samples)` -- ditto for `Sample` and `samples`.

Comment: Ahh! That may be it. So when I do for (Reference reference : references) am I in fact making a copy of reference? Could I do Reference &reference : references? Reference and Samples are Genomes and therefore quite large. Unfortunately I need to align all samples to all references so I don't know of another way that's not a nested loop.

Comment: Thank you @SamVarshavchik ! Changing it to references(&) in both the Reference and Sample loops made the difference.

Comment: Try using a profiler (for example `perf`) to gain insights.

Comment: `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock`, not withstanding its name which tends to trick beginners into using it, is not generally a high quality clock, and its implementation varies (and so does the quality of results it gives).  In worst cases, it is not even monotonic (i.e. time measurements don't increase with actual time).    Generally, it is recommended to use `std::chrono::steady_clock` to measure durations, not `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock`.

Comment: You are not accounting for object destruction. Also since the duration times are in seconds the objects are very slow.

Comment: IO costs are usually stochastic. You'd better defer the prints. Create a vector of duration with enough pre-allocated capacity (count of references). Then output results in a separate iteration.